# Normal bake contains blocky colors

Tags: uv, texture-baking, normal-map

When baking, the normal map comes out wrong. I'm using a cage, it is uv unwrapped and there no modifiers on the object. The thing is I have done this process on this object multiple times successfully, so I'm very confused.

[image: wrong normal bake]

Comment: could you please share your object or at least a part of it? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I tried it with a new cage and that solved the problem.

Comment: I solved the problem.